# NetworkManager in disconnected state

Tags: 13.04, networking, network-manager

There seems to be a problem with my network drivers. Neither eth0 nor wlan0 are recognized, and I'm running 13.04 over the 3.8.0-27-generic kernel.

Here's some diagnostic information:

1. `ifconfig` yields an entry for lo and some virtual ethernet bridges, but no eth0 nor wlan0.
2. `nm-tool` yields:

   ```
   NetworkManager Tool

   State: disconnected
   ```
3. `cat /etc/network/interfaces` yields:

   ```
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback
   ```
4. `lshw -sanitize -C network` yields:

   ```
   PCI (sysfs)

   *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 34
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33 MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7d00000-f7d01fff
   *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.2
       version: 0a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33 MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
   ```

What I've tried:

I tried to connect the NetworkManager Tool. From other sites, I've seen that it sometimes helps to change the file /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf from:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

To:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

And then doing a `sudo service network-manager restart` and/or rebooting the machine, but that has not worked either.

Any other ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: It might help to add info about your network devices e.g. the output of `sudo lshw -sanitize -C network`

Comment: What ethernet bridges? Is this running in a virtual machine?

Comment: No, this is in the host. I have a couple of ethernet bridges that I use for some virtual machines (using lxc).

Comment: This is exactly the issue I am having -- did you manage to resolve it? Also: http://www.xkcd.com/979/

Comment: No, unfortunately. I ended up moving everything I needed to an external hard drive and reinstalled Ubuntu. Haven't had the same problem since, though. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some years later ...

I recently hit the same issue in Ubuntu Mate 16.04 (kernel 4.4) with Broadcom 802.11 module and after some digging and questioning I found solved answer in stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45691434/nmcli-device-unavailable

Basically you have to delete the connection and start over with new connection after network-manager restart.

```
sudo nmcli c delete connection_name
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Time to time, it helps and sometimes you have to reboot whole machine. I am suspecting you have to also leave the wifi device resting for some longer time in order to get it working again (but that's purely subjective).

What helped me a lot - to run another terminal with monitor command:

```
mncli m
```

Anyway I consider this as a serious bug which is preventing me to use Ubuntu system smoothly and in production state, and it is really pity.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reinstall the network driver on Ubuntu, and monitor changes, including; new packages you install, and updates/upgrades made to your system.

How? Find the network driver in your install ISO. Use package manager or dpkg --install. Ran into this too, turns out some package was deselecting my driver in the additional drivers tab in system settings.